# fatal: adding files failed

Tags: github, fatal-error

I am new on github. Please provide me a better solution with explanation. 
I like to add Django files into github. But it shows the following error:

> fatal: adding files failed

My code is here:
        (venv) C:\Users\Tekson\Desktop\geo\basic>git init
        Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Tekson/Desktop/geo/basic/.git/

```
    (venv) C:\Users\Tekson\Desktop\geo\basic>git add .
    warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in basic/static/js/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js.
    The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
    warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in basic/static/js/lib/leaflet.ajax.js.
    The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
    warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in basic/static/js/lib/leaflet.ajax.min.js.
    The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
    warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in basic/static/js/lib/shp.js.
    The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
    error: open("data/wifi_network/nodes.shp.DESKTOP-OGJ64C4.10688.10176.sr.lock"): Permission denied
    error: unable to index file data/wifi_network/nodes.shp.DESKTOP-OGJ64C4.10688.10176.sr.lock
    fatal: adding files failed
```

Comment: try removing any lockfiles

Comment: What is that mean? I have no idea how to remove lockfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try finding this file:

data/wifi_network/nodes.shp.DESKTOP-OGJ64C4.10688.10176.sr.lock

and deleting it, and any other files with the ending .lock.

Lockfiles indicate when a file is being written to and are usually deleted once the application that uses the file closes, but sometimes when an application crashes they are not deleted and cause trouble.